# Non-bipartite non-weighted maximum matching between users

Tags: ruby, algorithm, matching, weighted, bipartite

The situation: A user selects multiple other users as possible partners for a project. The user has no preference for one user he picks over another (i.e. any user in his list is good enough for a partner). Example:

```
| user_id | preferred_partners |
| 1       | 2 4                |
| 2       | 3 1                |
| 3       | 4 2 1              |
| 4       | 1                  |
```

The real list will be much larger.

My question: given an array of users and their preferred partners (like the list above), I want to generate an array of final partnered pairs. The number of final partnered pairs must be maximized (I want to have as many people in pairs as possible).

This is the algorithm I *think* I need: [Edmonds's matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27s_matching_algorithm), but as I am not from a mathematical background, I'm having trouble interpreting and implementing it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Edmonds's matching algorithm is indeed what you want. This is a [good link](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~karp/greatalgo/lecture05.pdf) that offers a detailed explanation

Comment: The problem I'm having is implementing the algorithm in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Edmonds's algorithm might be what you want, but then again, it might not be. Are you ever going to look for triples? Are you ever going to want strength of preferences? Are you ever going to want some guarantees about your mechanism like, if someone puts down more preferences, they cannot go from being matched to not matched? Do partners have to be mutually preferred? If not, is there more weight on mutually preferred partners?

Some of these variants can be solved by Edmonds's algorithm or its weighted cousin, which uses Edmonds's to solve the "restricted primal" in much the same way that the Hungarian algorithm uses a bipartite matching algorithm, but some, 3D matching in particular, are hard and not amenable to cute combinatorial algorithms. You might find it easier to solve even the poly-time cases by calling an integer programming solver from Ruby.

Comment: No triples, only doubles. No preference strengths. Doesn't matter if some users are not matched. Partners have to be mutually preferred, but this problem can be easily solved by removing preferences that are not mutual from the data set prior to running the algorithm. I'm  99% sure that Edmonds's algorithm is the one I need. I just need help implementing it in Ruby/Python/PHP/etc.